# Google Search Console API Error 400 "parseError"

Tags: google-apps-script, parse-error, google-search-console

I try to retrieve data from the Google Search Console from Google Apps Script. Here's the script :

```
var token = getAccessToken()
var siteUrl = "https%3A%2F%2Fpeachday.co"
var payload ={
  "startDate": "2020-04-01",
  "endDate": "2020-04-21",
  "dimensions": [
    "query"
  ]
  }
var params = {
'Content-type': 'application/json',
'method':'post',
'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    'payload':JSON.stringify(payload)
}
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/" + siteUrl + "/searchAnalytics/query"; 
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)
Logger.log(response)
}
```

But I get that error

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input."
 }
}
```

Has someone faced that problem ?

Comment: How about modifying from `'Content-type': 'application/json',` to `'contentType': 'application/json',`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params)

Comment: I've been searching for hours... it finally worked, thank you so much !!